# Add a keyboard event listener that changes the speedX and speedY using the WASD keys

Tags: javascript, event-handling, keyboard, addeventlistener, interactive

this is my first post and I'm having a little trouble trying to finish my code, I have the basics done, but need some guidance: anyone willing to help?

Here's what I'm attempting to do, but struggling with: I've come to a stand still!

Add a keyboard event listener that changes the speedX and speedY using the WASD keys:
'W' increase SpeedY
'S' decrease SpeedY
'A' decrease SpeedX
'D' increase SpeedX

Make sure the SpeedX and Speed Y never go too fast

In the draw function, change the x and y position using the speedX and speedY variables.

If the circle is outside the canvas then move it to the other side.  For example, if the ball is over the right side of the canvas, then move it to the other side.  Make sure the ball is all of the way off the edge before moving it, otherwise it may pop.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;

var width  = 320;
var height = 240;

var speedX  = 0;    //how fast the ball is moving in the horizontal direction
var speedY  = 0;    //how fast the ball is moving in the vertical direction

var radius  = 10;


var x   = width  / 2  - radius;  //starting horizontal position
var y   = height / 2  - radius;  //starting vertical position


var circleColor             = "#FF0000";

var rectangleColorBg        = "#FFFFFF";
var rectangleColorStroke    = "#000000";


function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}


function circle(x,y,r, color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
}

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
    ctx.fillStyle   = rectangleColorBg;
    ctx.strokeStyle = rectangleColorStroke;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}


function draw() {

  //update based on speedX and speed y
  //update if the ball position is not inside the canvase.

  //draw the background - see function above
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  //
  //draw the circle - see function above
  circle(x, y, radius, circleColor);
}


init();
```

Comment: There are no traces of a keyboard event listener in your code.  What did you already try?

Comment: Sorry this is my most basic code, I posted it this way because my keyboard event listeners didn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you maybe put this code into a jsfiddle so we could help more easily?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see what you have tried so far, but here is some example code for the event listener part:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {
        // Move ('left');
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        // Move ('right');
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 38) {
        // Move ('up');
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
        // Move ('down');
    }
}
```

How far have you gotten with event listeners? you can also do `'keyup'` and such.

Comment: Some possibly useful game code can be found on a friend's github acct  [here](https://github.com/clee0/Bomberman/blob/master/gameScript.js). I'd be happy to help more once I understand the problem better - and if you need it.